# Display jquery dialog when Formview Delete button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dialog

Using a jquery dialog box, i'm trying to display the box when the delete button is clicked in the ASP.NET formview ItemTemplate.

Code for Function:

```
$(function () {
  $('#DeleteButton').click(function () {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
  });

  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({

      autoOpen: false,
      resizable: false,
      height: "auto",
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
          "Delete all items": function () {
              $(this).dialog("close");
          },
          Cancel: function () {
              $(this).dialog("close");
          }
      }
  });
});
```

i want to display the box when this button is clicked in the ItemTemplate:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"/>
```

However, the box is not being displayed.

my formview and ItemTemplate

```
        <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Car_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333">

        <ItemTemplate>
            Car_ID:
            <asp:Label ID="Car_IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Car_ID") %>' />
            <br />
            Car_Make:
            <asp:Label ID="Car_Make_FkeyLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Car_Make_Name") %>' />
            <br />
            Car_Model:
            <asp:Label ID="Car_ModelLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Car_Model_Name") %>' />
            <br />
            Car_Color:
            <asp:Label ID="Car_Color_FkeyLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Color_Name") %>' />
            <br />
            Car_Year:
            <asp:Label ID="Car_YearLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Car_Year") %>' />
            <br />
            Car_Price:
            <asp:Label ID="Car_PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Car_Price") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"/>
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="New" Text="New" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:FormView>
```

Current Function:

```
      $(function () {
      $("#<%= FormView1.FindControl("DeleteButton").ClientID %>").click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
      });
      $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({

          autoOpen: false,
          resizable: false,
          height: "auto",
          width: 400,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
              "Delete item": function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              },
              Cancel: function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              }
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Try `$('[id^="DeleteButton"').click(...)` instead of `$('#DeleteButton').click(...)` as in asp.net id is based on the master page and other factors.. so the actual id of the dom element is not exactly the same as you set always.

Comment: it is not working. i tried the code from the first answer too. i'm getting an error that the button is either not declared or not accessible due to it's protection level. is the button being inside the ItemTemplate of the formview have anything to do with that? @palaѕн

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't select `DeleteButton` properly with Jquery.

You need to get the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET by using [`ClientID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientid?view=netframework-4.8).

So it should be like this:

```
$("#<%= FormView1.FindControl("DeleteButton").ClientID %>").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: i'm getting an error that DeleteButton is not declared or cannot be accessed due to it's protection level. is it because the button being inside the itemtemplate of my formview?

Comment: How about if you try like  `$("#<%= YourFormViewID.FindControl("DeleteButton").ClientID %>").click..`?

Comment: i'm getting this error now  `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: `Line 12:   <script>
Line 13:       $(function () {
Line 14:           $("#<%= FormView1.FindControl("DeleteButton").ClientID %>").click(function () {
Line 15:               e.preventDefault();
Line 16:               $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');`

Comment: Could you please add more detail about your Form View to your question? Do you have `runat="server"` attribute on it?

Comment: added the code of the formview and ItemTemplate to question :)

Comment: Also please add `e` parameter to your click function like my answer `click(function (e)`. Otherwise it does not work properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210534/discussion-between-ahmad-noori-and-selim-yildiz).